# How can I make functional 'if' statement

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if ($variable=="x") {  
    $xs = 10;
}

if ($variable=="y") {
    $xy = 12;
}
```

I want to make functional `if` statement. Can I make this with loop instead of one by one?

How can I form this, like:

```
if $variable = a(0.) , b(1.) , c(2.) , d(3.) , e(4.) )  
$variables=(n+1)*7
```

Example:

```
if $variable = a  
n=0  
$variables=7
```

Example:

```
if $variable=d  
n=3  
$variables = 28
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$variables = (ord(strtoupper($variable)) - ord('A') + 1) * 7;
```

#### Explanation

`ord()` returns the ASCII value of the char, then you just subtract ASCII value of 'A' (first char of alphabet), then add one (from your formula) and multiply by seven

BTW I would recommend to test for `$variable` value before using the function...

Comment: @JuanMendes it seems that he want to return a value based on alphabet position (starting from zero) of a char ($variable), add one and then multiply by seven ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes* you can make this if check <sub><sup>(somewhat)</sup></sub> [*functional*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming):

```
$ifs = [ 'x' => 10, 'y' => 12 ];
$outs = [];
$variable = 'x';

array_walk($ifs, function($i, $k) use($variable, &$outs) {
    if($k === $variable) {
        $outs[$k] = $i;
    }
});

var_dump($outs);
```

I think the real question though is whether you actually want to.